# How to Recover overwritten database

Tags: mysql, backup

I just maked an huge mistake.I overwrite database with my old database backup which was 3 months older.
Is there any way that i can recover my orignal database with there record ??
please help me

Comment: This is a small chance — if you have 3 months of binary logs, from the time of the backup until current, you could apply the changes to the restored database. Read https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/point-in-time-recovery-positions.html

Comment: Look for OS backup - maybe it includes MySQL data directory? Look for shadow copies - maybe they are enabled?

Comment: new CREATE destroys InnoDB dictionary entries and further INSERTs very likely overwrite old pages. So, very small chance.